# google api information won't show up in console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have project where I am trying to get different book information based on radio buttons and a search bar.  There are 3 radio buttions and the plan is to search the text input based on the selected option. When I go to test I get no results. I've have watched a few tutorials and tried my  best to apply them to my spefic situation but they continue to give me no response.

heres the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchform").submit(function() {
    const searchTerm = $("#titleName").val();
    const selection = $('input[name="search"]:checked').val();

    if (searchTerm === '') {
      alert("Search Bar is empty");
    } else {
      switch (selection) {
        case 'ISBN10':
          if (validIsbn(searchTerm)) {
            $.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${searchTerm}`, function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            }).fail(function() {
              alert('Error: Could not retrieve book information.');
            });
          } else {
            alert("ISBN10 entered incorrectly");
          }
          break;

        case 'title':
          if (validIsbn(searchTerm)) {
            alert("ISBN10 has been entered. Please enter correct input.");
          } else {
            $.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${searchTerm}`, function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            }).fail(function() {
              alert('Error: Could not retrieve book information.');
            });
          }
          break;

        case 'author':
          if (validIsbn(searchTerm)) {
            alert("ISBN10 has been entered. Please enter correct input.");
          } else {
            $.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${searchTerm}`, function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            }).fail(function() {
              alert('Error: Could not retrieve book information.');
            });
          }
          break;

        default:
          alert('Please select a search category.');
          break;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
});

function validIsbn(ISBN) {
  ISBN = ISBN.replace(/[-\s]/g, "");

  if (ISBN.length !== 10) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!/^\d+$/.test(ISBN)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

and part of the html

```
        <section class="searchBar">
            <fieldset id="searchform">
                <label for="titleName"> </label><br>
                <input type="text" id="titleName" name="titleName" placeholder="Search Title, ISBN,  or Author "><br>
                <label for="opTitle">Title</label>
                <input type="radio" id="opTitle" value="title" name="search" checked>
                <label for="opISBN">ISBN10</label>
                <input type="radio" id="opISBN" value="ISBN10" name="search"><br>
                <label for="opAuthour">Author</label>
                <input type="radio" id="opAuthour" value="author"name="search">
                <button type="submit" id="Searchsubmit" name="Searchsubmit">Search</button><br>
            </fieldset>
        </section>
```

Comment: Hi, your submit handler will not get called as you are not having any `<form>` with id `searchform` its fieldset which has that `id` .